# Calculus problem with Euler's number and trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let  $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $f(x) = $$  x^2 \sin(e^{x^2}) \over  (x^4 + 1)e^{\sin(x)}$

Show that there exitst a real number $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ $f(x) \leq f(a)$

There was a hint that one shouldn't use the derivative here.

How do we go about something like this? Mean value theorem? But you need to find the derivative for that i guess.

Comment: Some crude approximations like $|\sin\theta| \leq 1$ will help.  I think that's probably what the hint refers to—if you're using the derivative you're working too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You function is always continuous. It is also bounded; indeed, using that $e^{-1}\leq e^{\sin x}\leq 1$, 
$$
|f(x)|=\frac{x^2|\sin(e^{x^2})|}{(x^4+1)e^{\sin x}}\leq\frac{x^2}{(x^4+1)e^{-1}}<e
$$
(using a crude estimation). We also see from the inequalities above that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0$.

So we have a continuous function that goes to zero at both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. Such a function always achieves its maximum and its minimum. The proof goes by using the definition of limit to guarantee that $|f(x)|$ is very small beyond some points $\pm k$. And on the interval $[-k,k]$, we have a continuous function on a closed interval so it achieves its maximum and its minimum.